# compareTo method: Object arg?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array using the compareTo method below. I am having a hard time understanding exactly what it does. I also don't get what Object arg is referring to. Can anyone explain to me exactly what this method does and how it works? The following code is what I have been working with...

```
public int compareTo (Object arg)
{
    if (salary > ((Employee)arg).salary)
        return;
    else if (salary == ((Employee)arg).salary)
        return 0:
    else 
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: Please add an extra line before your code so that it appears in a code block :)

Comment: thanks! Sorry i'm new at this

Comment: well it looks like its comparing an Employee's object salary (or a sub class of it) with a salary instance variable.

Comment: what does the Object arg mean?

Comment: Refer to - http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10 for best practices of implementing compareTo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there's an error - the first return should be `return 1`.

```
public int compareTo (Object arg)
{
    if (salary > ((Employee)arg).salary)
        return 1;
    else if (salary == ((Employee)arg).salary)
        return 0:
    else 
        return -1;
}
```

Now, let's look at the code.

The first thing to note is that we are coding to a contract - specifically, the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, which requires you to have a method `compareTo` that takes one parameter, call it `arg`, and returns an int. The int must be negative if `this` is smaller than `arg`, positive if `this` is greater than `arg` and 0 if `this` is equal to `arg`.

With that in mind, we begin coding. The only thing that we are allowing our Employee class to be compared to are other Employees - so we cast the object `arg` to `Employee`. If it is not one, an exception will be thrown.

Then, we simply compare our salary to its salary, and return 1 or 0 or -1 based on how the two Employees order. This allows Employees to have a natural ordering and be sorted, for purposes such as appearing in the correct order in `PriorityQueue` containers.

Answer (score 1):

`compareTo` is comparing `this` to `arg`, so `arg` is what you are comparing to. Effectively, this code seems to compare Employees by comparing their salaries. 
Assuming the line that says `return;` is meant to be `return 1;`, the code could be written as

```
public int compareTo (Object arg)
{ 
    Integer thisSalary = this.salary;
    Integer otherSalary = ((Employee) arg).salary;
    return thisSalary.compareTo(otherSalary);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm going to assume that the first 'return' should actually return 1.

What it is doing is returning an ordering. By returning 1, it is saying that the object 'arg' should come AFTER the current object (ie. it should have a higher index). Similarly, a value of -1 states that it should come BEFORE, and a value of 0 means that it is equal and that ordering doesn't matter as much (although different sorting algorithms may behave differently with these elements, a property known as [stable sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aStable_sorts)).

Answer (score 0):

The Object arg means that your compareTo will receive any object, not just Employee objects. This can be usefull if you want to compare two objects of different classes (imagine you would want to compare a class Person with a class Dog and return true if they both had the same weight).

In this specific case you will be casting arg into Employee, meaning you will treat the specific object as an Employee instance.

I advise adding an "if (instanceof(Employee))" before your code. This will mean you will only run your code in case arg is really an Employee. (Example: if(instanceof(Dog)) would prevent trying to transform a Person into a Dog). This is usefull since trying to cast an incompatible type will lead to an exception.

Answer (score 0):

> I also don't get what Object arg is referring to

In order to sort an array of items, you have to be able to grab one of the items and compare it to another item.  Many such comparisons need to take place in order to fully sort the items.  compareTo() is a method that you define in the class that all the items in the array belong to.  The compareTo() method allows the sort routine to grab one item in the array and call compareTo() on that item.  The argument to the compareTo() function is another item in the array.  The return value of the compareTo() method tells the sort routine how to order the two items.